# How does angular distinguish router-outlet tags anchored in multiple components

Tags: angular, router-outlet

In app.component.html we have a < router-outlet > which it will dynamically load other modules and components and views.

but if we have a 2nd component (imported in a different module) with its own < router-outlet >

how does angular distinguish between the 2 existing router outlets for example, how does angular know

"router1" (containing path:"/url-1" path:"/url-2") gets loaded in app.component.html. and
"router2" (containing path:"/url-3" path:"/url-4") gets loaded in secondComp.component.html

when both app.componen.html and secondComp.component.html have this tag specifically < router-outlet >

how does angular know which router definition needs to be used/loaded by x component.

Just for learning purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular concept of routing is define that in app.component.html which is global routing means application default UI or parent route is render from it. & in our routing file we are distinguish path for parent & child path of routing let say as example:

app.component.html

```
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

### app.module.ts

in imports section

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'Login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
      { path: 'Home', loadChildren: () => import('./librarymanagement/librarymanagement.module').then(m => m.LibraryManagementModule) },
```

])

So all parent level routes are render at parent level [Login, Home]
so this both route treat as parent route.

now in Home route load feature module called `LibraryManagementModule`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LibraryManagementComponent,
    children: [{ path: 'Dashboard', component: DashbordComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
      { path: 'country', component: CountryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  }
```

Now child route loads its child called [ Dashboard,country ] inside Home `route`. as child of `RouterModule`.

```
RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

So all route treat as tree to indicate the specific identifier to call.
inside `LibraryManagementModule` bootstrap component is `LibraryManagementComponent` which contains

### LibraryManagement.component.html

```
<div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: using your example, because the parent route is lazy loading the librarymanagement.module, which contains as import the "child" router class then Angular creates this Tree struct, for each defined router and so on for the next lazy loaded modules in the router. but now I have a question, how does the app.componet.html is wired to understand to use the Router Module imported in the app.module.ts , thanks in advance for this detailed explanation and taking the time :)

Comment: App.component is bootstrap component which we have given to app.module.ts so that app.component know thay this route  need to be load.