# Angular 14.2.8 Lazy Loading not creating Chunks

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm rather new to Angular and have tried implementing Lazy Loading but unable to see chunks while loading

**here is my project structure** :

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**my code as follows**:
features routing module

```
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {  Routes,    RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './HomeComponent/home-component.component';
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: HomeComponent, children:[
        { path: "home", component: HomeComponent }
    ]},
   

];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FeatureRoutingModule {

}
```

features module

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HomeComponent } from "./HomeComponent/home-component.component";
import { FeatureRoutingModule } from "./feature.routing.module";
import { Signup } from "./SignupComponent/signup.component";


@NgModule({
imports: [FeatureRoutingModule ,CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],// importing loaded childs here
declarations:[Signup , HomeComponent]// declaring components here
})

export class FeatureModule {

}
```

app-routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CatalogComponentComponent } from './catalog/catalog-component/catalog-component.component';

const route1: Routes=[
  {path:'catalog' , component: CatalogComponentComponent},
  {path: 'home' ,  loadChildren: ()=> import('./FeaturesModules/feature.module').then(m=>m.FeatureModule)}
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(route1)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app-module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HeaderComponentComponent } from './shared/header-component/header-component.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FeatureModule } from './FeaturesModules/feature.module';
import { CatalogComponentComponent } from './catalog/catalog-component/catalog-component.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponentComponent,
    CatalogComponentComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FeatureModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HeaderComponentComponent } from './shared/header-component/header-component.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FeatureModule } from './FeaturesModules/feature.module';
import { CatalogComponentComponent } from './catalog/catalog-component/catalog-component.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponentComponent,
    CatalogComponentComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FeatureModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

edit : updated app routing module module path
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqlgR.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7GPS.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHR4F.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB60q.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNp3e.png
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz3qg.png

Comment: sure have replaced images with code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't define feature modules into app module, it will defeat the purpose of lazy-loading.

Here in your code:

> @NgModule({
> imports: [FeatureModule   ]
> bootstrap: [AppComponent]
> })
> export class AppModule { }

https://github.com/kmohan0910/farm.io/blob/84aadadac987a48ac766a191008cb0f4b1b2b761/src/app/app.module.ts#L27

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy , was struggling for 2 days . it's working now

Answer (score 1):

As per your implementation in your parent module only one route is define which is home module so when your application load at that time when you click `home` Route then `FeatureModule` invoke aspect of that module.

If you want to test lazy loading then add some other route in app.routing module and when app load at that time lazy module not getting load but when you click route of lazy load modue then get the lazy load module

Comment: i have tried adding catalog as a separate path in app routing and have again tested but still failing

Comment: have updated the path as null in app routing now , still not working

Comment: Have you add catelog as one separate route or module? If you define catelog as simply route then defult route for the same.

Comment: Please check the answer of this question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74414590/how-does-angular-distinguish-router-outlet-tags-anchored-in-multiple-components/74415031#74415031

Comment: have added as a separate route in app routing and also declared seperately

Comment: Yes you can find it in above comment question's answer which i have given

Comment: have tried adding as children still no use : https://github.com/kmohan0910/farm.io